# Change Directory DOS 8086 Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, directory, x86-16, dos

I'm working on a program that uses directories in 8086 assembly.

I'm searching a code to change directory like the "cd" command on terminal.

Comment: does this help? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308980/dos-instruction-3bh-on-emu8086-changing-working-directory)

Answer (score -2):

if you want to change your emu8086.exe file path (suppose you have change your current exe file from d: drive to c: drive ) then use the following command on cmd

setx path "%path%;c:\emu8086

but you have to remove old path